# Force Haskell Stack build to use the Resolver Specified after Shebang

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

I'm trying to use haskell for scripting in the pattern specified here on the "Script interpreter" section:

> https://haskell-lang.org/tutorial/stack-script

When I have comments like this in my script after the shebang:

```
#!/usr/bin/env stack
{- stack
    --resolver nightly-2016-11-26
    --install-ghc
    runghc
    --package http-conduit
-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
```

I know I can safely say run:

```
$ stack myfile.hs
```

And it correctly picks up the resolver version I specified I need.

However, if I also try to build my script, to have the best of both worlds in scripting for development while I figure things out, and compilation once I'm more sure...

```
username@myhost:~/$ stack exec -- ghc myfile.hs && ./myfile
Run from outside a project, using implicit global project config
Using resolver: lts-7.10 from implicit global project's config file: /home/username/.stack/global-project/stack.yaml
```

That will error out because it's using resolver 'lts-7.10' from my global config instead of 'nightly-2016-11-26' even though my comments after the shebang specify a specific, non-global resolver to use.

While I know I could run ghc above and explicitly call --resolver on the command line, I would prefer if this were picked up from what's within the file itself.  Is this possible?

Comment: It is not all that satisfactory, but you can temporarily change the script so that it uses `exec -- ghc` on its own. Within the magic comment, replace `runghc` with `exec` and add `-- ghc` plus whatever options you want to pass to GHC at the end (I'm mentioning these obvious-sounding details because Stack is rather picky about the order of the options).

Comment: Thanks, that gave me an idea to use the cpp preprocessor, something like #ifdef GHCI
    exec
#else
    runghc
#endif
But this naturally failed because it needs to finish reading this section to run this...